# Android, SQLite, Firebase: how to display data from SQLite after you have logged in using Firebase in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, sqlite

So I am working on an Android application (written in Java) that implements Firebase authentication (registers user on Firebase and such), but once I log in no matter with what user I try, all the data from SQLite is shown to all the users.

Is there a resource where I can look into how to connect Firebase authentication and displaying data from Firebase for a specific user only? In general, how should I approach this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to make a similar development. In my application, there were 3 different user roles and they had different authorizations from each other. To handle this, when the user registered with email and password, I also saved information about this user to firestore [such as Name, Surname, Mail, Role].Thanks to this process, when the user logged in with mail and password, I saved the reference id of the user document containing the logged in mail in the shared preferences.Thus, when necessary, I pulled the user's role with this id and showed what he should see or hid what he should not see

Comment: `Separation of concerns`. This concern is sperated as IAM (identity and access management). I would Google for Firebase+IAM.. It'll lead us how this concern is addressed by others.

Comment: I noticed I have not been clear enough - the data that I want to be displayed comes from local SQLite database, not from Firebase (using just the authentication from it). Would it still work that way with different role implementations?